# Xamarin Forms UI Animated Menu

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm rather new to Xamarin Forms and I am finding some of the rigidness of the UI to be difficult to deal with and would like some expert input. Basically what i'm trying to make is a preferably sleek menu UI like [Example Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbMjR.png) (crudely drawn in MS paint) that is nothing more than a list of menu options, and when you click one, the ones below it slide or move down a bit to make room for an area with additional descriptive text. Also, if the menu option opens up and the other options no longer fit on the screen, I would want them to remain out of scope in a ScrollView.

Now my issue is that I don't really know the best way to go about it. My thoughts:

I am currently attempting to nest a grid inside of a scroll view and formulate some kind of function that will add an empty row definition under the indexed menu option button, and populating the empty row. Basically using adding/removing grid rows to handle the 'expanding and contracting' of the menu option. I am struggling to get this function bug free right now but I am wondering if animating this action is possible with a smooth easing sliding motion or if I should explore better easier options. It seems silly to constantly clear the grid and re-add all of the update rowdefinitions each time.

I am curious if perhaps dynamically changing the specific buttons row height when clicked might be cleaner than adding/removing rows. Or using a listview and changing the listview cell's height when clicked. Or would a stacklayout work best in this case since it is technically a stack of buttons. Is it best to add/remove rows or are there easier/better ways to handle this?

Essentially, I am looking for some pointers on which direction I should take that makes the most convenient sense. I chose to start with a grid because it seemed easiest to work with in this case but when looking to animate the menu option and make a sleek smooth menu I am starting to have doubts.

Thanks!

p.s. If someone can also provide or link me a relevant example of how an animation in this case would go down it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: For the animation part you can look here: http://www.redbitdev.com/cross-platform-animations-using-xamarin-forms/?utm_source=Xamarin+Weekly+Newsletter&utm_campaign=132820e355-Issue_0395_7_2015&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_07f5b54b81-132820e355-266901469

Comment: I don't think that this kind of "custom control" can be made efficiently in Xamarin.Forms. You may need a custom renderer. In other words, you need to develop your control in Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS and consume from the Xamarin.Forms part.

Comment: I was just looking into custom renderers right now but it begs the question why even using Xamarin Forms if i have to customize something as simple as a slide menu to the point where it's no longer shared UI? Or would i run into the same issues developing the UI if i wasn't using forms and just used Xamarin Native anyways?